# Side by Side <div> then regular <div>

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have been goaded into humility by HTML and CSS:

Trying to mimic the following:
[image]

This is my attempt:

```
<div>
  <div style="width:800px;">
    <div style="float:left;width:25%;background-color:red;">Facility #: COMPANY10</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:green;text-align:center;">FACILITY_112</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:25%;background-color:blue;text-align:right;">Facility Code: 4071</div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:800px;">
    <div style="float:left;width:25%;background-color:red;">Date: Jul 17, 2014</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:green;text-align:center;">Custom Assessment (UDA) Report</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:25%;background-color:blue;text-align:right;">User: John Wayne</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Time: 12:59:11 ET
  </div>
  <div>
    <hr/>
    Assessment Type: 1 - Braden Scale for Predicting Pressure Sore Risk
    <hr/>
  </div>
</div>
```

This results in:
[image]

How can I fix this, please help.

Comment: You should avoid inline-CSS. Besides cluttering your code and making it hard to read, it also makes debugging more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this in the 3nd `div`

```
clear:both;
```

So it looks something like this

```
<div style="clear:both;">
   Time: 12:59:11 ET
</div>
```

**Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/EZ7wU/

Comment: this brings the <hr/> middle div and the last <hr/> to the next line, but not the time.

Answer (score 1):

Just limit the width of your outermost `<div>` to 800px, too.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `width: 800px` to the main container :

```
<div style="width:800px;">
  <div>
    <div style="float:left;width:25%;background-color:red;">Facility #: COMPANY10</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:green;text-align:center;">FACILITY_112</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:25%;background-color:blue;text-align:right;">Facility Code: 4071</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div style="float:left;width:25%;background-color:red;">Date: Jul 17, 2014</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:50%;background-color:green;text-align:center;">Custom Assessment (UDA) Report</div>
    <div style="float:left;width:25%;background-color:blue;text-align:right;">User: John Wayne</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Time: 12:59:11 ET
  </div>
  <div>
    <hr/>
    Assessment Type: 1 - Braden Scale for Predicting Pressure Sore Risk
    <hr/>
  </div>
</div>
```

*...and avoid inline CSS*

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to force a floating div to a new line, just use clear:

```
<div style="clear:left">
```

This will ignore whatever divs are currently floating left and any new float left elements will consider the next line as their top.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding inline css and maintaining a better html structure.

Add the content you want in the second row to a single seperate div:

```
<div style="clear: both;">
  <time>Time: 12:59:11 ET</time>
  <div>
    <hr/>
    Assessment Type: 1 - Braden Scale for Predicting Pressure Sore Risk
    <hr/>
  </div>
</div>
```